# Unrecognized escape sequence for path string containing backslashes

Tags: c#, .net, string, path, escaping

The following code generates a compiler error about an "unrecognized escape sequence" for each backslash:

```
string foo = "D:\Projects\Some\Kind\Of\Pathproblem\wuhoo.xml";
```

I guess I need to escape backslash? How do I do that?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You can either use a double backslash each time

```
string foo = "D:\\Projects\\Some\\Kind\\Of\\Pathproblem\\wuhoo.xml";
```

or use the @ symbol

```
string foo = @"D:\Projects\Some\Kind\Of\Pathproblem\wuhoo.xml";
```

Comment: This also helped to resolve an Html.TextBoxFor issue that I was having. Using the @ before the regular expression resolved the Unrecognized escape sequence, where the double backslash failed.

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
string foo = @"D:\Projects\Some\Kind\Of\Pathproblem\wuhoo.xml";
```

The problem is that in a string, a `\` is an escape character. By using the `@` sign you tell the compiler to ignore the escape characters.

You can also get by with escaping the `\`:

```
string foo = "D:\\Projects\\Some\\Kind\\Of\\Pathproblem\\wuhoo.xml";
```

Comment: FWIW and to help Googlebot, the term for @"" is a "verbatim string literal". Though I've also heard it referred to as just "string literal", that technically includes the "regular string literal" of just "". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 14):

```
var foo = @"D:\Projects\Some\Kind\Of\Pathproblem\wuhoo.xml";
```

Comment: On a minor note, a " is then escaped like ""

Answer (score 13):

If your string is a file path, as in your example, you can also use Unix style file paths:

```
string foo = "D:/Projects/Some/Kind/Of/Pathproblem/wuhoo.xml";
```

But the other answers have the more general solutions to string escaping in C#.

Answer (score 5):

```
string foo = "D:\\Projects\\Some\\Kind\\Of\\Pathproblem\\wuhoo.xml";
```

This will work, or the previous examples will, too. @"..." means treat everything between the quote marks literally, so you can do

```
@"Hello
world"
```

To include a literal newline. I'm more old school and prefer to escape "\" with "\\"

Comment: But double " are not treated literally.