# C# Regex Issue "unrecognized escape sequence"

Tags: c#, regex

I have an issue with the regular expressions I'm using but don't know how to continue with them. I get the error "unrecognized escape sequence".

I am trying to list out all files that could have a phone number in the formats listed in the code below

```
static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        //string pattern1 = "xxx-xxx-xxxx";
        //string pattern2 = "xxx.xxx.xxxx";
        //string pattern3 = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx";

        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\BTISTestDir");

        foreach (string filename in fileEntries)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            string regexPattern1 = "^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{4}$";
            string regexPattern2 = "^((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}$";

            if(Regex.IsMatch(content, regexPattern1))
                Console.WriteLine("File found: " + filename);
            if(Regex.IsMatch(content, regexPattern2))
                Console.WriteLine("File found: " + filename);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and use `(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[\s\.-]\d{3}[\.-]\d{4}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognized escape sequence for path string containing backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use `@` to make the strings no longer use the escape character `\`:

```
string regexPattern1 = @"^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{4}$";
string regexPattern2 = @"^((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}$";
```

As a side note, I think you want the two `if`s at the end to be a single `if` with an or (`||`) between the two conditions.

Comment: I could be wrong, and this may be a new format, but a [`string literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) needs the `@` before the quote, not the variable name.

Comment: @Blindy: You can be lucky there is no changelog for the answer yet ;p

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, `@identifier` *is* valid C# syntax <.<

Comment: @Blindly Thanks. Also for the thought of combining the if statements. Now it accepts my regex but i'm not getting any files returned and I know that it should be returning stuff... weird. I made a text file with those patterns in it.

Comment: @Blake, give me an example of the file names you made. They should be like `123.456.1234` with nothing else around them.

Comment: [code]
string regPattern1 = @"(\()(\d)(\d)(\d)(\))(\s+)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)";
                string regPattern2 = @"(\d)(\d)(\d)(\.)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\.)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)";
                string regPattern3 = @"(\d)(\d)(\d)(-)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)";
[/code]

Answer (score 9):

Add an additional '\' to unescape the escape.  When it's processed it will then be interpreted in the manner you intended.

Comment: +1 because this works beautifully in the rare case that you have to escape a double quote (") character. (ex. \\\")

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not the regex, but the string. Before compiling it to a regex with the call to IsMatch(), the text you enter is still a normal string and it must obey the language rules.

\d in your language is not a recognized escape sequence, hence the error. You can either double backslashes (\ is the escape sequence to get a ) or, as Blindy pointed out, you can prefix your constant strings with a @, telling the compiler that it should not try to interpret anything looking like an escape sequence to it.