# Unrecognized escape sequence when using a path as a SQL parameter

Tags: c#, string, sqlparameter

I am trying to store a string or `nvarchar(500)` in SQL. When I pass a full file path as a string parameter, there is an error unrecognized escape sequence.

Since path is not an usual param that this stored procedure expects, how can I open this possibility so it can accept string such as `c:\foldername\subfoldername`. Am I suppose to add `@` at the begging of a string or use a StringBuilder?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognized escape sequence for path string containing backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since backslash is considered as a special character(**escape**), it's causing the issue. Use `/` or `\\` in the path as:

```
      c:/foldername/subfoldername
      c:\\foldername\\subfoldername
```

OR as you said, use `@` in the front as :

```
     @"c:\foldername\subfoldername"
```

**EDIT**: For Javascript, I will simply replace the `\` to `/` as below:

```
     path = path.split("\\").join("/");
```

Comment: this field is used as a notice field, and i cannot expect from user to know that. as an alternative, using regex to fix this is overkill.

Comment: @John AS you mentioned, you may want to put `@` in the front as other option.

Comment: but what if I am passing it from a javascript to a webservice? How to prepare this string in JS for a webservice?

Comment: @John If javascript, then you can easily replace the `\` with `/` by `path = path.split("\\").join("/");` before passing the values to next layers of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can also escape the backslash() by adding the @ to the front of the string for example

```
@"This\Is\Some\Path"
```