# How to Store file path in asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#

Hi I need to store file path of my folder on as string variable in ASP.Net MVC 4  but when I'm using the following method it shows an error

> Unrecognized Escape sequence

```
static string path="C:\Path";
```

What is the reason of this error and how can I solve this????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the '\' with another '\', like so:

```
static string path="C:\\Path";
```

or put an '@' in front of it like so:

```
static string path = @"C:\Path";
```

Duplicate: [Unrecognized escape sequence for path string containing backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-string-containing-backslashes-in-c-sharp)

Related reading: [2.4.4.5 String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is because a backslash in C# is used to mark the next character as its literal interpretation.  For example if you wanted a quote inside your string you would precede it with `\` to prevent the string being closed early:

```
var myString = "This is my string with \"quotes\"";
```

This is called escaping.  In order to display a blackslash within a string you either need to escape it with another slash:

```
static string path = "C:\\Path";
```

Or precede the string with the @ symbol, which suppresses the backslash escape mechanism:

```
static string path = @"C:\Path";
```