# How do I write a backslash (\) in a string?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I want to write something like this `C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Tasks` in a `textbox`:

```
txtPath.Text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+"\Tasks";
```

I get the error:

> Unrecognized escape sequence.

How do I write a backslash in a string?

Comment: Use double backslash \\ or put @ at the start of your string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes

Comment: @Precious1tj: I would guess maybe they downvoted you because if you googled "C# Unrecognized escape sequence" you would have easily found an answer without having to post a question.

Comment: @Precious1tj Perhaps because [googling your question title](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+i+write+a+backslash+(%5C)+in+a+string) would have lead you to an answer? I didn't downvote, so I don't know for certain.

Comment: @Nolonar: I like how the first result is _this question_. [**INCEPTION**](http://inception.davepedu.com/)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I know; this just shows how fast Google is. However, the "first" result is not the only one with valid answers.

Comment: @Nolonar: I know, just fun to see. :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair How was i supposed to know???..I googled my title and didn't find anything helpful

Comment: @Precious1tj: I didn't say your title, but your [error message](https://www.google.ca/webhp#psj=1&q=Unrecognized+escape+sequence). But FYI, for future googlings, be sure to include "C#" in your search. For example, the _first result_ when googling your title with "C#" yields [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1275075.aspx/1)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The backslash (`"\"`) character is a special escape character used to indicate other special characters such as new lines (`\n`), tabs (`\t`), or quotation marks (`\"`).

If you want to include a backslash character itself, you need two backslashes or use the `@` verbatim string:

```
var s = "\\Tasks";
// or 
var s = @"\Tasks";
```

Read the [MSDN documentation/C# Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) which discusses the characters that are escaped using the backslash character and the use of the verbatim string literal.

*Generally* speaking, **most C# .NET developers tend to favour using the `@` verbatim strings** when building file/folder paths since it saves them from having to write double backslashes all the time and they can directly copy/paste the path, so I would suggest that you get in the habit of doing the same.

---

That all said, in this case, I would actually recommend you use the `Path.Combine` utility method as in [@lordkain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18532812/1269654) as then you don't need to worry about whether backslashes are already included in the paths and accidentally doubling-up the slashes or omitting them altogether when combining parts of paths.

Comment: @MattyAB: How are you inspecting the resultant string? If you're checking it out in the Visual Studio debugger, it will show it with escape characters added.

Comment: Additionally, using `Path.Combine` is OS agnostic, so this code could be run on both *nix and windows machines

Answer (score 20):

To escape the backslash, simply use 2 of them, like this:
`\\`

[If you need to escape other things, this may be helpful.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

There is a special function made for this [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)

```
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var fullpath = path.Combine(folder,"Tasks");
```

Answer (score 5):

Just escape the `"\"` by using + `"\\Tasks"` or use a verbatim string like `@"\Tasks"`

Answer (score 2):

```
txtPath.Text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+"\\\Tasks";
```

Put a double backslash instead of a single backslash...

Answer (score 0):

even though this post is quite old I tried something that worked for my case .

I wanted to create a string variable with the value below:

```
21541_12_1_13\":null
```

so my approach was like that:

- build the string using verbatim

  string substring = @"21541_12_1_13\"":null";
- and then remove the unwanted backslashes using Remove function

  string newsubstring = substring.Remove(13, 1);

Hope that helps.
Cheers

Comment: This would be very cumbersome and error-prone if the `string` contained multiple backslashes.  Also, why insert a backslash just to immediately remove it?  `newsubstring` doesn't contain the desired text, anyways, but `substring` already does.