# Add Single Quote in String Builder

Tags: c#

i wants to add Single Quote to string value Received from object

sb.Append(`"<input type='button' id='buyNow_"+i+"' class='GetQuote' onclick='return getProposerSection('"+ objResponse.objQuoteDetails[i].PlanName+ "')'/>"`

Comment: I don't find any `StringBuilder` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is this:

```
sb.Append("<input type='button' id='buyNow_"+i+"' class='GetQuote' onclick='return getProposerSection(\""+ objResponse.objQuoteDetails[i].PlanName+ "\")'/>"
```

Notice the double quotes at the beginning and end of your attribute value.

Comment: Thats my string 
sb.Append("<input type='button' id='buyNow_"+i+"' class='GetQuote' onclick='return getProposerSection('"+ objResponse.objQuoteDetails[i].PlanName+ "')'/>"

Comment: Alright, then try the updated answer. Notice the escaped double quotes (\") and then check the resulting string in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash ("\") character for escaping the character

check link [How do I write a backslash (\) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/how-do-i-write-a-backslash-in-a-string)