# Add \ to a string with quotes in c#

Tags: c#

I need to add a '\' to a string

I try this

```
 var Filename = name.Replace("'", "\'");
 name = Filename ;
```

if name = he's here

name.Replace("'", "\'") will return : "he\\'s here"

what I need is: he\'s here

Comment: so do you want to replace ' with \\ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/how-do-i-write-a-backslash-in-a-string

Comment: You know wherever you use `"he\\'s here"` it's gonna come out as `he\'s here`. So I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: Where are you seeing "he\\'s here"? In the debugger?

Comment: Yeah, if it's debugger - then you're seeing the full string escaped. Nice Ed.

Comment: my bad it's a debugger !!! thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a backslash (\‌) in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/how-do-i-write-a-backslash-in-a-string)

Comment: @EJoshuaS: related but not really duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `name.Replace("'", "\'")` does nothing because `"'" == "\'"`. So `name.Replace("'", "\'")` returns "he's here" (you can try it in https://dotnetfiddle.net/). What you want is: `name.Replace("'", "\\'")`

Second if you inspect name in the debugger (in watch window or immediate window) you will get `"he\\'s here"` because that is how you should write a string constant in c# to get `he\'s here` into a variable.