# C# regx expression can anyone solve

Tags: c#

1. At least one lower case letter,
2. At least one upper case letter,
3. At least special character,
4. At least one number
5. At least 8 characters length

problem is showing error at "/d" in regx pattern

```
private void txtpassword_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Regex pattern = new Regex("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*/d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z/d#$@!%&*?]{10,12}$/");
    if (pattern.IsMatch(txtpassword.Text)) {
        MessageBox.Show("valid");
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
        txtpassword.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: `/d`should be `\d`.

Comment: If I were you, I would put each rule into a separated `Regex` object, and test your string against them each. This way, the rules are much easier to read, understand, maintain, and extend.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})
```

[Tests](https://regex101.com/r/3IHFOw/1)

Comment: Moien Tajik can you explain the code as i am new learning c# does this satisfying all the necessary things as above mentioned

Comment: @shayaaz Yeah, It's ok for all of your needs. If you visit the link I had mentioned and hover on regex characters, it will simply tell you what it does. And I have added UnitTests which proves it works correctly based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In regex, the backslash is used to escape. 
So instead of /d it should have been \d.

But you could also just use [0-9] instead.

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])\S{8,}$
```

Also, when using backslashes in a string.
Then either double backslash.  Or use a verbatim string. F.e. @"foobar"

More about that in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/).

**Example C# code:**

```
string[] strings = { "Foo!bar0", "foobar", "Foo bar 0!", "Foo!0" };

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])\S{8,}$");

foreach (var str in strings){
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1} valid.", str, rgx.IsMatch(str) ? "is" : "is not");
}
```

**Returns:**

```
[Foo!bar0] is valid.
[foobar] is not valid.
[Foo bar 0!] is not valid.
[Foo!0] is not valid.
```

Comment: not allowing s and S showing error cannot build when using your regx code for c# application

Comment: showing error in code LukStorms error in s and S not allowing

Comment: I just added info about using a verbatim string. Backslash escapes in normal strings.

Comment: @shayaaz  Also, no need for the forwardslashes? F.e. @"\w+"