# No overload of the 'ToString' method takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have this problem:

```
blTimer.Text = (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
              .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

At this point:

```
ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

Visual Studio shows me the error in the title. How I can resolve?

Comment: You should always *COPY/PASTE THE EXACT ERROR MESSAGE*!  SUGGESTION: change your format string, e.g. `ToString("hh:mm:ss");` or `ToString("hh/mm/ss");`.  The backslash ("\") typically indicates an "escape sequence": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-160

Comment: What is `startTime`?

Comment: @KlausGütter it's this:

 var startTime = DateTime.Now;
 var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 }

Comment: What is the .NET version/platform of your project? The `TimeSpan.ToString(string format)`  was introduced in .NET Framework 4.0. Don't mix .NET Framework 2.0, .Net Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, please consider changing your format string, e.g. `.ToString("hh:mm:ss")`.

The backslash ("\") typically indicates an "escape sequence": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-160

See also [How do I write a backslash (\) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18532722/421195)

---

ADDENDUM:

There are a few things that *could* be going wrong, including:  a) the errant backslash in your format string, b) applying the format string to the wrong data type, c) other?

Since it sounds like you've fixed the backslash, I'm guessing maybe the current problem is that you're invoking `.ToString()` on the wrong data type (a type that *ISN'T* a `System.DateTime` object).

SUGGESTIONS:

- When in doubt, one powerful troubleshooting technique is to split your "complex expression" into "individual statements".
- Another powerful technique is to write a "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example" - an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Here is an example:

```
using System;

/*
 * SAMPLE OUTPUT:
 * endTime: 12:00:00
 */
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse("10/18/21 11:00:00");
            DateTime endTime = startTime + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            string s = endTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
            Console.WriteLine("endTime: {0}", s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried but same.. Not working

Comment: I will add to the question the full line error.

Answer (score 2):

RESOLVED :D

The problem was the framework version when i created the project i didn't saw the version of .net so that was the problem!
Thanks everybody for helping me!

@paulsm4 - Yep. Thank you, that code is useful for me on some other projects thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if `startTime` is of type `DateTime` there is nothing wrong. `TimeSpan` has an overload `ToString(string format)` and your format works. Tested in PowerShell.

Comment: eh. But for vs is an error so i can't compile it..

Comment: btw thank you for replying to me :)

Comment: @ThatGuuy Visual Studio has no such problem. If it did, every .NET developer would have noticed. Post actual code that reproduces the problem. The code you posted works fine