# How to concatenate double quotes with slashes to a string value in c#.net?

Tags: c#

How to concatenate double quotes with slashes to a string value?

Expected out put: `"\"Hello World\""`

Here is my code:

```
string term="Hello World";
string output = "\"" + term + "\"";
```

above code result is giving `Hello World`

Comment: @RandRandom please note expecting output `"\"Hello World\""`  not just `"Hello World"`

Comment: `above code result is giving Hello World` seems a wrong statement as it outputs `"Hello World"`

Comment: `string output = $"\"{term}\"";`

Comment: The number of people not reading this question properly is worrying. OP wants the text output to include the quotes and slashes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a backslash (\‌) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/how-do-i-write-a-backslash-in-a-string)

Comment: Btw if your code should be more dynamic you could consider implementing one of those solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal | see an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iV7k6M

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
string output = "\"\\\"" + term + "\\\"\"";
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rCXJze)

Answer (score 1):

```
string output = "\"\\\"" + term + "\\\"\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

To output quotes and slashes you should use slash before symbols(slash, quotes etc.)
In your case

```
string term = "Hello World";
string output = "\\\"" + term + "\\\"";
```

First slash is used to output second slash and third slash used to output quotes.
I don't know whether I should consider first and last quotes in your question or not. If you want to output them just add

```
\"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must escape every char, that you want to display.

`\"Hello World\"`:

```
string output = "\\\"" + term + "\\\"";
```

`"\"Hello World\""`:

```
string output = "\"\\\"" + term + "\\\"\"";
```

Comment: Please note the expecting output should be `"\"Hello World\""` not `\"Hello World\"`

Comment: sorry then you must add two escaped doubles quotes: `string output2 = "\"\\\"" + term + "\\\"\""; `

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could add the escape characters yourself, but what if you want to escape values inside the string too? You could write that loop yourself easily enough, or;

```cs
public string Escape(string value)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(value), writer, null);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```