# How to find USB HID DevicePath?

Tags: c#, usb, hid

I've been working on USB HID Device in embedded system and C# for a while. I decided to use USBHid library in C#. I got the ideal result with this library. But I have a problem. While defining the USB in the USBHid library, the following code is sufficient in the project of the library that I found on the internet.

```
public UsbHidDevice Device;
Device = new UsbHidDevice(vvvv,pppp);
```

However, when I use the same library, it asks me for an expression in the following format.

```
public UsbHidDevice Device; string vidandpid = 
"\\hid#vid_0000&pid_0000&mi_00#a&0&000000000&1&0000#{eeof37d0-1963-47k4-aa41-74476db7uf49}";
Device = new UsbHidDevice(vidandpid);
```

I adapted this format for my own HID device, but without success. How should this string expression be? I am open to your views. Thank you from now.

How to find USB HID DevicePath?

Comment: Don’t add tags to question titles, that’s what tags are for. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: You may consider looking at values for devices such as your keyboard to see the format. Open PowerShell and execute the following command: `Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_PnPEntity WHERE PnPDeviceID like '%HID%'"`. One can also use `regedit` to view the registry keys/subkeys/values. In the registry look under subkeys in: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID`

Comment: The following may also be helpful: [How do I write a backslash (\) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/how-do-i-write-a-backslash-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on USBHID library and found solution with HidLibrary library. As far as I understand, HidLibrary falls short on some issues.

Here I am sharing the C# code that I linked with HidLibrary. Thank you for all the replies.

```
device = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorID, ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
   if (device != null)
   {
       device.OpenDevice();
       device.Inserted += DeviceAttachedHandler; 
       device.Removed += DeviceRemovedHandler;
       device.MonitorDeviceEvents = true;
       device.ReadReport(myfunction);
   }
   else { RtBox_Feedback.AppendText("NOT DEVICE!"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`\\hid#vid_0000&pid_0000&mi_00#a&0&000000000&1&0000#{eeof37d0-1963-47k4-aa41-74476db7uf49}` - is a device interface for the `{eeof37d0-1963-47k4-aa41-74476db7uf49}` interface. It is almost always unique and semi-random for each device. It also may change if yore put device in another USB slot. This string may be used as path to open this "file" with `CreateFile` Win32 API and talk with device by means of interface-specific IOCTLs. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-device-interface-classes).

For HID devices Windows have another device interface GUID - [GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-hid) - `{4D1E55B2-F16F-11CF-88CB-001111000030}`

You can use [CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_listw) or [SetupDiGetClassDevs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw)/[SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinterfaces)/[SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetailw) APIs to enumerate device interfaces by [interface GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-device-interface-classes) or by device [Instance ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids).

Mentioned "USBHid library in C#" may already have code that doing such enumeration and filtering by HID deivce VID/PID but I cannot say it for sure since you haven't added link to the code of this library. :)

Comment: I got it. It was difficult, but I solved it. Thank you :)