# Searching for backslash character in string in C#

Tags: c#, string, indexing, indexof, backslash

I am strugling with getting the index of sequence "\a\b" in string. Any idea how to do it? I am doing following:

```
string expr = "Hello\a\b";
Console.WriteLine(expr.IndexOf("\a\b"));
```

This code returns 0 instead of expected 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a backslash (\‌) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/how-do-i-write-a-backslash-in-a-string)

Comment: No, that is different. If I understand it correctly writing IndexOf(\\a\\b) will search for character \. However I am looking for \a and \b which are different character. Please correct me if I am wrong. The output for my case is correct only when using IndexOf("\a\b", StringComparison.Ordinal).

Comment: If you indeed have characters ``\a`` ([alert](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0007)) and ``\b`` ([backspace](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0008)), then yes, that duplicate is wrong for you and the accepted answer is correct. However, not only these characters are rather unusual in a string, you are also explicitly saying in the title of the question that you want to search for the backslash character, for which that duplicate is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string expr = "Hello\a\b";
var inx = expr.IndexOf("\a\b", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Refer to documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.StringComparison?view=net-6.0