# image save path giving runtime error

Tags: c#, emgucv

whenever I am trying to save the webcamera capture image  automatically then then runtime error is coming in path.automaticaly name like 0.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg like this way image will save in the particular mention folder.but giving run time error.
plz check this.

```
namespace camera1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Capture capture;
        private bool captureinprogress;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {
           Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
           cameraimage.Image = ImageFrame;
           string root = "C:\\photo\0"; // automatically saving image to c drive like       001.jpg,002.jpg;
           for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           {
               if (File.Exists(" "))
               { }
               else
               {
                   string Path = root + i + ".jpg";
                   ImageFrame.Save(Path);
               }

               {
                   if (ImageFrame != null)
                   {
                       pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
                   }
                   if (pictureBox1 != null)
                   {
                       pictureBox2.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
                   }
                   if (pictureBox2 != null)
                   {
                       pictureBox3.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
                   }
             }
         }
     }
     private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        if (capture != null)
        {
            if (captureinprogress)
            {  //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text
                // "Start" for resuming capture
                btnstart.Text = "Start!"; //
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
            }
            else
            {
                //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button
                // Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
                btnstart.Text = "Stop";
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }

            captureinprogress = !captureinprogress;        
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (capture != null)
            capture.Dispose();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code..

Comment: Also post the error you are getting after reformatting your code.

Comment: ImageFrame.Save(Path); still error coming on this line

Comment: Then please add the error to your post, so we can stop guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mask the backslashes, or the compiler will try to interpret `\p` oder `\0`, which he can't

So the easiest way to accomplish this is to add an `@` at the start of your string.

```
string root = @"C:\photo\0";
```

Or you use double-backslashes all the time:

```
string root = "C:\\photo\\0";
```

For further reference, please read:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/as2f1fez.aspx
- [Unrecognized escape sequence for path string containing backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: I think you mean `@"C:\photo\0";`.

Comment: Serv you could have just edited my code instead of marking it down.

Comment: @Serv ok sorry I am taking my negative back.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a instance here but you need to change this to

```
string root = @"C:\photo\0\";// instead of string root = "C:\\photo\0";
```

**note:** You cannot save directly into C: Drive because you need to run the program with administrative privileges. I suggest using a folder on desktop or some library folder such as My Pictures.

Comment: i tried. ImageFrame.Save(Path); still error coming on this line

Comment: @Nirupum just as I suspected Serv and Me we were both wrong and my first answer was correct. You just need to add an end '\' so you get the folder '@"C:\photo\0\"' instead of file.

Comment: sir,i tried with slash but giving the same nullreference exception in the line   ImageFrame.save(path);

Comment: @Nirupam Does the Folder  '@"C:\photo\0\"' exist on the disk? Also note that you cannot save directly into C: Drive because you need to run the program with administrative privileges. I suggest using a folder on desktop or some library folder such as My Pictures.

Comment: '@"C:\photo\0\"'--its giving error like cannot implicitly convert type char to string,too many character in character literal,unrecognized escape sequence..

Comment: i tried to do in @"D:\photo\0\".same null reference error.once i tried to save in c drive.it save 6 image starting from 0010 to 0060.jpg like.then i start the project again and then again null referece exceptiob is coming.