# Unrecognized character \C is irresolvable. Why?

Tags: c#, regex, match

```
Match m = Regex.Match("\\\\server1\\Cold Folder1\\title and text number06220-03-15-2015.pdf", "\\\\server1\\Cold Folder1\\(title and text number.*\\.pdf)");


Match m = Regex.Match("\\\\server1\\Cold Folder1\\title and text number06220-03-15-2015.pdf", @"\\server1\Cold Folder1\(title and text number.*\.pdf)");
```

Both ways give me the error "Unrecognized Escape Character `\C`. And I am stumped as to why.

What do I have to change to get this result?

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} produces the filename: {1}.", m.Groups[0].Value, m.Groups[1].Value);

// \\server1\Cold Folder1\title and text number06220-03-15-2015.pdf produces the filename: title and text number06220-03-15-2015.pdf
```

Full error: Unhandled Exception: System. ArgumentException: parsing `"\\server1\Cold Folder1\(title and text number.*\.pdf)"`

Comment: Put a `@` before the `"`, like `Match(@"`

Comment: Hint: backslash is an escape character in regular expressions, *as well* as in C#. So if you want an actual backslash in the text to match, you need to double it in the regex... which means either `@"\\"` or `"\\\\"`

Comment: What? Here. I'll put up the complete error in the question. I've done everything you've already said.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: install a regex design program, like Expresso from Ultra Pico, and type your regex pattern into it.  Expresso will show you a "visual" representation of your pattern which will help you understand what Jon Skeet told you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognized escape sequence for path string containing backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I understanding what you were saying now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using @ in both? input and regex match

```
Match m = Regex.Match(@"\\server1\Cold Folder1\title and text number06220-03-15-2015.pdf", @"\\\\server1\\Cold Folder1\\(title and text number.*\.pdf)");
```

EDITED: Thanks Alan Moore

This should work

I hope this helps

Comment: He had the right number of backslashes already.  All he needs to is switch to a verbatim string by adding the `@` as you said..

Answer (score -1):

In the first line in question regex:

```
"\\\\server1\\Cold Folder1\\(title and text number.*\\.pdf)"
```

error is in `\\Cold` and `\\(title` - it should have double slash `\\\\Cold` and `\\\\(title`

In the second line in question regex:

```
 @"\\server1\Cold Folder1\(title and text number.*\.pdf)"
```

there are two errors:

- `\Cold` should have double slash to represent slash: `\\Cold`
- `\(title` mean `(`, should be `\\(title` to represent `\` and `StartGroup`

---

Working code:

```
Match m = Regex.Match("\\\\server1\\Cold Folder1\\title and text number06220-03-15-2015.pdf", @"\\\\server1\\Cold Folder1\\(title and text number.*\.pdf)");
Console.WriteLine("{0} produces the filename: {1}.", m.Groups[0].Value, m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why. Like it is now, it's not a good answer. I need to pick a hex editor and compare your code to OP's code to find the difference.