# Display Image based on drop down selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a drop down with list of doctors. What I would like to do is when you select on a name from the drop down list, to display a image.

The problem I am having is to search through the image folder and compare it with the name that was selected from the drop down.

Here is what I attempted to do below which does not work:

```
string imgPath = "\\AccessExpress\ASPCode\OCUpgrade52\images";

if(Directory.Exists(imgPath)){

    string Name = Parameter_SelectName;//Contains the selection from drop down

    if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(imgPath, Name)) )
        Response.Write("true");
    else
        Response.Write("false");
}
else
    Response.Write("false");
```

Getting the following error: **CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence**

And having a hard time to grab the image that matches the selection to display

**Update**: I was able to resolve the issue with the following (I hope this helps others who are having similar issues):

Here is what i have so far:

```
string imgFolderPath = @"\\AccessExpress\ASPCode\OCUpgrade52\images";

bool folderExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(imgFolderPath);

if(folderExists){
string urlPath = "http://oc2-reatest/OCUpgrade52/images/";
string imgName= Parameter_SelectName + ".png";
string img = string.Concat(urlPath,imgName);

bool fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(imgFolderPath, imgName));

if(fileExists)
Response.Write("<img src='" + img + "' />");

else
Response.Write("File Does Not Exists");
}

else
Response.Write("Folder Does Not Exists");
```

Comment: use double `\\ ` instead of single `\ `

Comment: ...or prefix your string with `@`. For example, `string imgPath = @"\\AccessExpress\ASPCode\OCUpgrade52\images";`

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Can you explain why double?

Comment: @user9808783 because it is special symbol in C# strings

Comment: Backslash is a special character in strings. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Ohh, i see you changed what you entered. I was confused why you added the three slashes "///" and getting "The name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes

Comment: @IlyaBursov not really a duplicate as in my question I am asking something differently

Comment: `Parameter_SelectName` needs to contain the extension of the file, not only the file name. Make sure the value you're getting from the combo box includes it.

Comment: @JoshPart: Could I append the extension and add it to the string Name? Also, the folder isnt being recongize at all

Comment: Yes, you can append the extension to the string Name. If the folder isn't being recognized, make sure you or the user your program runs with has access to such folder.

Comment: @JoshPart: Okay, I will see about the path to the folder.

Comment: \\ path means that it is not in your local drive (aka it is on network). Are you sure that your app has privillege to access that location?

Answer (score 0):

I think just a small change to your code would do it. Once you take the doctor's name from the comboBox or drop-down, I guess you're passing it directly to find whether the file exists or not.

Try this :-

```
            string Name = "Parameter_SelectName";
            string path = imgPath + Name + ".jpg"; //jpg being the extention of the pictures
            bool fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(path);
```

I hope that'll do the trick.