# C# Split Textbox.Text includes the backslash

Tags: c#, webforms

As I read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes) since I have similiar issue about the backslash.
On my webform textbox, I input some thing on like `VN\Mary`.
I would like to Split this textbox.Text as 2 words.
the Split worked very well in VB.Net , after I moved to C#, it starts to have problem.
Would anyone give me some advice ?
I even tried `textbox.Text.ToCharArray()` but it does not work if I use `VN\Thomas`.
I would appreciate your advice.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in C#. Try `textbo.Text.Split( new Char[] { '\\' } )`.

Comment: Uhm, is `VN\Thomas` meant to represent a Windows Active Directory login name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string[] words = textbox.Text.Split('\\');
```

EDIT: escape the backslash

Comment: This doesn't compile: `'\'` is an invalid `char` literal: backslashes must be escaped.

Comment: hi @peemerdu,
I checked, the function is working but it does not work on WebApi when I pass object as 
`{
  "loginID": "a2vn\thomasl",
  "password": "password",
} `
by using the same `Text.Split('\\')`  , it does not work.
Would you have suggestion ?

Comment: @TàiLêHữu - You could do this a few ways which is outside the scope of the original question. Is this in JSON format? I would parse this into an object and run the above solution against the value of the property.